# How can I get gesture metrics (GESTUREMETRICS) info on Windows 8 Desktop

Tags: winapi, windows-8, touch, gesture, pan

Windows embedded and mobile allow one to use the SystemParametersInfo function to retrieve a GESTUREMETRICS structure (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ee500273.aspx) which gives the threshold and timeouts for various touch screen gestures that the system will detect.

I am really interested in finding the "minimum distance that a touch contact must move across the surface for a pan gesture to be recognized" (GID_PAN) but I cannot figure out how to find this information on Windows 8 desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data isn't exposed via any public API.  It's hardcoded to 2.7 mm.

Comment: Perhaps in a registry setting?

Comment: Nope; they're built into the gesture recognizer.  Why do you need this?  Are you building your own gesture recognizer?

Comment: I am using InjectTouchInput and I want to be able to take these thresholds into account when performing certain gestures

Comment: Edited answer to give the values.

Comment: Oh and do you have the values for the other gesture metrics?

Comment: Which metrics are you looking for?  (I got the information from the source code & headers.)

Comment: @Alex that's *only* for Phone and Windows Compact edition.   That structure isn't defined in the desktop headers.

Comment: Is there a list of these values somewhere to be found (for the MS Surface)? I'm implementing a gesture recognizer, and while I could just estimate them myself, I'd prefer to follow Windows (would be nice if they define them in the headers at some point in the future).

Comment: @Alex this is *rapidly* moving into a different question.   If you're using (or mocking) WM_GESTURE, you're using relatively ancient technology.   The appropriate APIs are to use the pointer APIs directly and create a [GestureRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer) where you can customize any values you want.

Comment: I'm processing WM_POINTER and the output is my own internal thing, which will figure out the gestures itself. I stumbled upon this question looking for the touch equivalent of `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXDOUBLECLK | SM_CYDOUBLECLK)`. Turns out it doesn't exist. If the user can't decide these values, then at least Microsoft must have come up with a set of workable values that they use. I would like to know what these values are. I'm sorry if that's a different question.

Comment: @Alex If you ask a separate question, I'll answer it. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503293/what-are-the-gesture-metrics-built-into-the-windows-gesture-recognizer :)