# What are the gesture metrics built into the Windows gesture recognizer?

Tags: winapi, touch, metrics

I started looking for the touch equivalent of `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXDOUBLECLK | SM_CYDOUBLECLK)`, but any list of values will do. So far I have found these: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ee500273.aspx

Comment: This doesn't sound like a practical programming question. You are essentially asking us to guess/reverse engineer the software. Why do you need to know? What are you going to do with that information?

Comment: Implement a gesture recognizer. Instead of figuring out the values myself, I thought it better to use values that are known to work well. "Why do you need to know?" For a similar reason as I would need `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXDOUBLECLK | SM_CYDOUBLECLK)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That structure isn't part of Windows any more. The current structures are internal to Microsoft; however, the current values are:

- 200 himetric units in X and Y for the touch to be considered a tap;
- 450 himetric units in X and Y for two taps to be considered a double tap.

Comment: Thank you so much!